# Vectorize/optimize rolling pandas calculation on row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have a data frame:

```
df_dict = {
    'sum': np.nan,
    'src1': [5, 1, 1, 5, 1],
    'src2': [2, 6, 2, 4, 1]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
```

I am currently updating the 'sum' column via doing:

```
def transform(x):
    row_num = int(x.name)

    previous_sum = 0
    if row_num > 0:
        previous_sum = df.at[row_num-1,'sum']

    src1 = df.at[row_num,'src1']
    src2 = df.at[row_num,'src2']

    df.at[row_num,'sum'] = previous_sum - src2 + src1

df.apply( lambda x: transform(x), axis=1)
```

Which results in the correct Output:

```
   sum  src1  src2
0  3.0     5     2
1 -2.0     1     6
2 -3.0     1     2
3 -2.0     5     4
4 -2.0     1     1
```

The problem is over a large dataframe with many rows, and repeating this across many columns it is very slow.

I would like to optimize it to somehow utilize some inbuilt pandas/numpy vectorizing if possible, or any more optimized solution.

My example at a better solution

```
df['sum'] = df['sum'].shift() - df['src1'] + df['src2']
```

Which leads to incorrect output

```
   sum  src1  src2
0  NaN     5     2
1  NaN     1     6
2  NaN     1     2
3  NaN     5     4
4  NaN     1     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df['sum'] = df['src1'].cumsum() - df['src2'].cumsum()`.

Comment: It's the same; just subtract one cumulative sum from the other.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Macus, much appreciated

Comment: @AndreeCrist if my answer works, please accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are performing cummalative sum.

This can be achieved by cumsum() function

```
df['sum'] = df['src'].cumsum()
```

results in

```
sum     src
0   1   1
1   3   2
2   6   3
3   10  4
4   15  5
```